# Extract audio from video in Linux with a GUI program?

Tags: audio, gui

When I use Thunar I like adding to custom actions command lines like those presented [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/339245/47206), [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/294426/47206) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/288571/47206) to extract audio from videos. I mean **without transcoding/altering the sound, just putting it out of the video** (a flv or mp4 video, for example, is a aac audio - which cannot be played as such, but rapped into a m4a, like in the the command in the links posted. a webm video has a ogg audio which needs to be extracted.)

Now, I am using elementayOS, and will not use Thunar, nor Nautilus, just Pantheon-Files.

I want to know if there is a GUI solution to achieve this.

Comment: to do that in terminal: avconv -i "INPUT FILE" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "OUTPUT FILE". it is fast - instant!

Comment: avconv is a forked project from ffmpeg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv. You can do the exact same thing as I've described in my answer too.

Comment: @slm - i got myself an answer by using avconv commands with nautilus actions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better than trying to add context menu commands to the minimalist Pantheon-Files of Elementary OS or to use other media applications to extract sound from video, I guess the most simple is just to install Nautilus (it is not at all problematic in eOS, contrary to Thunar, which comes with the whole Xfce environment).

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Then install [Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-actions/) and open it..

I will provide an example for extracting audio (aac in m4a container) from flv and mp4 video files.

Define a new action, give it a name, maybe an icon too. Check - 'Display action in selection context menu'.

[image]

Under the command tab, add the command

`bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${0%%.*}".m4a' %f`.

[image]

Under Execution tab there are options to select depending on what you want to see during and after the action (open terminal, report).

Under *Mimetypes* tab, enter the filters for the type of files in the context menu of which you want to see the command - in this case: `video/mp4` and `video/flv`.

[image]

There are other options, but these look sufficient for the purpose of my question.

[image]

Similar actions can be added to extract sound from other types of video and, of course, for other very different purposes.

(This solution is based on suggestions and solutions present in the links already posted in the question and the credit goes to the authors.)

---

Can be used in Thunar custom actions too.

My initial source is [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/235912/47206).

Answer (score 6):

#### Command line

If you're willing to forgo using a GUI you can use `ffmpeg` fairly easily to do this.

#### Sample file

If you go to [QuickTime: Sample files](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1425), you can download this sample file, [sample_mpeg4.mp4](http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4.zip). After downloading it, unzip it.

```
$ ls -l | grep sample
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   235829 Nov  4  2005 sample_mpeg4.mp4.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml   245779 Nov  3  2005 sample_mpeg4.mp4
```

#### Example

You can extract the AAC audio frpm the mP4 file.

```
$ ffmpeg -i sample_mpeg4.mp4 -vn -acodec copy sample_mpeg4.aac
FFmpeg version 0.6.3-rpmfusion, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May  5 2011 19:20:01 with gcc 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)
...
...
Output #0, adts, to 'sample_mpeg4.aac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: aac, 32000 Hz, stereo, 48 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
size=      31kB time=4.99 bitrate=  50.4kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:30kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 3.594943%
```

The resulting AAC file.

```
$ ls -l |grep sample
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    31468 Oct  4 22:09 sample_mpeg4.aac
-rw-r--r-- 1 saml saml   245779 Nov  3  2005 sample_mpeg4.mp4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   235829 Nov  4  2005 sample_mpeg4.mp4.zip
```

You can also use `ffmpeg` to confirm the file format:

```
$ ffmpeg -i sample_mpeg4.aac 
...
...
Input #0, aac, from 'sample_mpeg4.aac':
  Duration: 00:00:05.59, bitrate: 45 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: aac, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 45 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

#### GUI

You can use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) and it's Convert/Stream feature to do this. After launching VLC.

#### Example

#### Select Convert/Save from File pulldown

[image: ss #1]

#### Select video file, and convert stream

[image: ss #2]

#### Start the conversion

[image: ss #3]

Comment: @cipricus - AAC and WEBM are there.

Comment: @cipricus - no I am not positive, I would double check the dump raw input option, also poke around the options menu under the screwdriver/plyer icon next to audio.

Comment: See here: https://wiki.videolan.org/Extract_audio/

Comment: sorry. in fact the only audio output options are: mp3, ogg, mp3 (mp4), flac, cd. so, no solution aac-m4a for flv and mp4 videos (youtube). (where is AAC?) webm is ogg audio. but there seems to be transcoding anyway as there's an option to set the bitrate. trying to output webm as ogg i got nothing anyway

Comment: I'm not sure where the codecs for VLC come from, they might need to be installed separately.

Comment: the wiki clearly states that the extraction as such is possible: there is a part called "Extracting audio in original format" - but only CLI

Comment: @cipricus - yeah I saw that too, trying to figure out if it's exposed in the GUI. Seem's like it should be.

Comment: i am not able to understand CLI just use commands provided by others. and the wiki talks about DVD mostly. i do not know how to adapt that to flv. my original commands that i used in thunar would be usable in terminal too i guess, but need to be adapted

Comment: @cipricus - I think I see part of the problem, don't pick convert in the 2nd dialog, pick stream. There's a wizard where you can select to extract the audio from a file in it's a original format.

Comment: @slm the codecs for VLC are all in libvlc AFAIK, it plays just about any codec on Earth without additional installation of codec.

Comment: @cipricus - still trying to figure out how to do this with VLC, BTW!

Comment: i hoped to use my old commands and now i can do it in nautilus - see my answer - and i guess that qualifies as a GUI solution. i use vlc as main player and love it but not for transcoding and such. although many people recommend it i was never able to use it as supposed for these purposes. i guess mixing clever commands and the GUI of the file browser is a good alternative

Answer (score 0):

I have good solution :

```
#!/bin/bash 
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
    find $1 -iname "*" -a -type f  -exec ffmpeg -y -i {}  {}.mp3   \;
# restore $IFS
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

You should call :

```
./myscript.sh youroootpathofvideos
```

Comment: i was asking for GUI (graphical not terminal) commands. and not to convert to mp3, but to extract audio as such

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised how hard it is to find a good tool for this, but here's my choice:

FFmulticonverter is a very basic gui for avconv/ffmpeg. You can Put files in with drag&drop and optionally save the Outfiles in their original location - that makes it very fast for me.

and you can just use the code:

`-vn -acodec copy` like in `avconv -i INPUT.mp4 -vn -acodec copy OUTFILE.m4a`

There's presets for it but at the moment it uses `.aac` as file-extension and i suggest you use `.m4a`.

Answer (score -1):

[Losslesscut](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut)

Select "tracks" section

[image]

Identify the audio track to extract as separate file.

[image]